# problema logar google no android

Tags: android, apache-cordova, google, login, app

Estou tendo muita dificuldade em logar no google com android, tenho uma app, em cordova, configurei minha app, tenho credenciais no google.

Estou seguindo esse exemplo:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#android

pagina de configuracao da app no google:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

Meu problema esta nessa parte pra frente, 
https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin

keytool -exportcert -keystore "C:....android\debug.keystore" -list -v -alias fotos

essa linha nao roda no console:

C:...\www>-alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:...android\debug.keystore"
'-alias' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

C:...www>keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore

"C:....android\debug.keystore"
'keytool' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Peguei esse exemplo:https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Problema acho que se resume:
Certificacao da apliacao no google, gerar uma chave sha1, pelo que entendi tem que rodar um comando no console, mas ele da erro, nao sei obrigatorio essa certificacao, resumindo nao estou conseguindo gerar a chave sha1, talvez isso que seja problema, ae da mensagem de retorno com valor de erro 8. Estou dias vendo isso e nao encontrnou solucao.

Comment: Teria como você colocar o erro na sua pergunta?

Comment: C:\projetos\fotos\www>keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
'keytool' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve ir na pasta onde está o Keytool, ele é uma aplicação e não deve estar no PATH do seu sistema, por isso aponta esse erro que você descreveu. Então ela está na pasta de bin do Android, procure pela raiz e depois na pasta bin tem varios .exe, lá está seu keytool, (1) você pode apontar pra lá e executar de uma vez, ou (2) pode ir pro diretório (cd "diretorio de executaveis do android") e executar lá mesmo. Essa chave é essencial em vários momentos no desenvolvimento de Android Apps.